# Graph contained in a metric space

Tags: graph-theory, metric-spaces, geodesics, graph-distance

I have a metric space $X$ and a graph $G=(V,E)$ whose set of vertices is a subset $V\subset X$ (and $E$ is the set of edges, which is a symmetric subset of $V\times V$). For each $v\in V$, the set of neighbours of $v$ (elements of $V$ that lie on the same edge as $v$) is infinite and the distance between $v$ and its neighbours is unbounded. However, I have some good properties:

(1) There is a group of isometries of $X$ that preserves the set $V$ and the set of edges, with finitely many orbits (on the set of vertices), so we can study what happens locally.

(2) The graph is connected.

(3) The paths of $V$ have good properties. Given two elements $v,w\in V$, I will say that **a path of length $n$ between $v$ and $w$** is given by $v=v_0,v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n=w$, all vertices of $V$, where $(v_i,v_{i+1})\in E$ for each $i$. Then, for all $v,w\in V$, we can find a path between $v$ and $w$ of minimal length by the following algorithm: we define $v_0=v$, and then for $i\ge 1$, choose $v_i$ in the set of neighbours of $v_{i-1}$ to have minimal distance (in $X$) with $w$. This way is not unique, but **all paths produced have the same length, which is the minimal length of paths between $v$ and $w$**.

My question is then the following: **can we interpret (3) by some geometric way?** Is there a name for this? Does it have some good natural properties? For example, what does it say about the embedding of metric spaces $V\hookrightarrow X$ (where we endow $V$ with the metric given by the graph distance) ? It is certainly not isometric as edges have unbounded distance but maybe it is not too bad?

Thanks for your help.

PS: I am not at all expert in graph theory, the graph I am talking about comes from algebraic geometry.

Comment: In (1), I presume you meant to say only that the set $V$ has finitely many orbits, not the set of edges, right? I ask that because the distance between neighbors of $v \in V$ is unbounded and the group action is by isometries, hence there are infinitely many orbits of edges.

Comment: Also, I am unconvinced by the argument in (3) that all paths produced have the same length. It seems to me there could be both a length $3$ path $v=v_0,v_1,v_2,v_3=w$ and a length $2$ path $v=v_0,v'_1,v'_2=w$ produced by the same process. Both $v_1,v'_1$ have equal (and minimal) length to $w$ amongst all neighbors of $v_0$. Also, $v'_1$ is a neighbor of $w$, so $v'_2=w$. But $v_1$ is not a neighbor of $w$ and the neighbor of $v_1$ which is closest to $w$ is $v_2$.

Comment: Or, are you simply asserting that this uniqueness of length is a *property* of your situation?

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks for the comments. Yes, in (1) I meant on $V$, I changed it. In (3), it is true that in general it could happen that the algorithm that I give does not give paths of the same length, but it is (surprisingly?) the case in my case. My question is exactly to know if this behaviour has a name, or if it has good properties (what can we deduce from this?)

Comment: Okay, now I understand. But, I don't have any name to put on that property.

Comment: Does it imply something on the embedding of $V$ into $X$? (something like quasi-isometry, or local properties of geodesics, or anything similar?)

Comment: Certainly not quasi-isometry: As you have already pointed out, the neighbors of $v$ have distance $1$ in $V$ but unbounded distance in $X$.